# Convert "survfit()" output to a matrix or dataframe

Tags: r, summary, survival

Example data below.

My basic problem is that running "survfit" by itself gives a nice column with median lifespan for each category, which is the thing I want to extract from my survfit data. Ideally I'd like to export this "survfit" output as a dataframe/table and ultimately save to .csv. But I get errors however I try.

Thanks for help/advice!

**Example data:**

```
df<-data.frame(Gtype = as.factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C")),
Time=as.numeric(c("5","6","7","7","7","7","2","3","3","4","5","7","2","2","2","3","3","4")),
Status=as.numeric(c("1","1","1","1","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")))

library(survival)
exsurv<-survfit(Surv(df$Time,df$Status)~strata(df$Gtype))
exsurv
```

**and the "survfit" output I want to get as a dataframe:**

```
> exsurv<-survfit(Surv(df$Time,df$Status)~strata(df$Gtype))
> exsurv
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(df$Time, df$Status) ~ strata(df$Gtype))

                   n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
strata(df$Gtype)=A 6      4    7.0       6      NA
strata(df$Gtype)=B 6      6    3.5       3      NA
strata(df$Gtype)=C 6      6    2.5       2      NA
```

**edit:**
*An earlier version of this question included the print() function superfluously. "print(survfit)" and "survfit()" give the same result.*

Comment: Look at the structure `str(exsurv)` of the object. Surely you will find the data that is printed. (not tested)

Comment: You could use the `broom` package, for example:  `results <- broom::tidy(exsurv)`, that will give you a data frame, with the parameters in columns.

Comment: Was curious specifically in the median lifespan statistic, as this is calculated stratified by Gtype by default in the print() function, but not with summary(exsurv), str(exsurv), broom::tidy(exsurv).

I just realized print() is superfluous to this too.

Just running 

    survfit(Surv(df$Time,df$Status)~strata(df$Gtype))

already gives the same result as print(exsurv) from my example...

Answer (score 4):

Yes `broom::tidy` function works.

`'mymk1'` - is the object output of using survfit on my raw survival data set

I tried this and it worked well

```r
results <- broom::tidy(mykm1)

write.csv(results, "./Desktop/Rout/mykm1.csv") 
## the output csv file created in my folder Rout inside my Desktop folder.
```

The csv file can then be imported easily into any word or spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I was making it way more complicated by not understanding the basic survival function. The basic summary(exsurv) does give you median lifespan, mean lifespan, confidence intervals, etc... from the survfit function.

```
exsurv<-survfit(Surv(Time, Status)~ strata(Gtype))
```

You can put the summary(exsurv) data into a table using the code below

```
survoutput<-summary(exsurv)$table
```

And then just save to .csv as an ouput

```
write.csv(survoutput, file="exsurvoutput.csv")
```